# Circular nature of the cosmos. (π)

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, universe

I've been pondering the irrational number that is pi and how it relates to the infinity of the universe. We often see many cycles in nature, current scientific theory states that the universe began as a spec of matter that exploded into the universe we know, and that in time it will regather all it's particles into another spec and explode again, repeating this circular process an infinite number of times.

Pi is an irrational number, used in calculations of circles. There is no end to it, it is infinite, like the universe. Is there a relationship here?

Comment: Someone will probably ask you to frame a more specific question. I'd just mention that there's no known or theorized relationship between the existence of irrational numbers and the origin of the universe. That doesn't mean that there isn't any such connection! Only that if there is, we are quite far from having any way to formalize or understand it.

Comment: I don't know how to clearly articulate what I was thinking. I was mostly curious to know if anyone else had put any thought into why pi was irrational, or whether anyone had wondered if there was a reason behind why circumferences of circles could only be calculated using an irrational number. I'm just going to let this one close.

Answer (score 3):

Pi is not infinite; indeed it is smaller than the very finite number 4. What is infinite is the number of digits you need to represent pi in decimal representation. But that's a thing it shares with every irrational number, like the square root of 2, the golden mean, or the Euler number e.

Moreover, this cyclic universe you describe was never the mainstream cosmology, and is furthermore contradicted by newer data which tells us that the expansion of the universe accelerates (that's the reason why dark energy was introduced as explanation), which means that the universe most probably will not regather its particles even once, let alone an infinite number of times, but will expand forever.

Note that in all those scenarios, pi has still the same value, because the value of pi is completely unrelated to the fate of the universe; it's a purely mathematical concept, although it is indeed also used in descriptions of the universe. But if you look at *real* circles, you'll probably find not a single one for which the quotient of circumference and diameter is exactly pi. For one, as we know since Einstein, space is not exactly Euclidean but curved; circles in curved spaces generally have a different quotient of circumference and diameter (although in the vicinity of earth the deviation is too small to be measured). On the other end, from quantum considerations we know that there must be a minimal length on the order of the Planck length (about 1.6*10^-35 meters),  so there's absolutely no way to get infinite precision on anything finite in real space.

And indeed, even if you look at a more formal level, there's one difference between the infinity of the decimal representation of pi, and the infinity of the cyclic universe: The digits of the decimal representation of pi are sequentially numbered by the natural numbers: They go on infinitely, but they have a clear start (the decimal representation of pi *starts with* 3.14159…). On the other hand, to sequentially number the cycles of the cyclic universe you need the integers: They go on infinitely in *both* directions. Not only would there be infinitely many cycles in the future, but also there would have been infinitely many cycles in the past.

OK, finally *one* thing both infinities have in common: Both are countable infinities. That is, you can do an 1:1 mapping between both the cycles of the digits of pi and the natural numbers, and of the cycles of the cyclic universe and the natural numbers (but for the latter only if you don't insist on consecutive cycles getting consecutive numbers).

Comment: Touche... +1, but I'm still interested in hearing more answers. Very convincing answer though.